# Сайт недоступен для некоторых посетителей

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, проблема в том , что сайт  не открывается у людей имеющих интернет  от некоторых операторов и такое встречается у немногих посетилелей по всей России. Хотя большая часть свободно заходит что с домашней сети , что с мобильных операторов. Как решить проблему, где начать испытать косяки?

Comment: стоит поймать конкретного посетителя, у которого не открывается сайт, и начать диагностику с его машины

Comment: Допустим у меня есть такой пользователь. А с помощью каких средств это можно сделать?

Comment: Этот посетитель получает какую-то конкретную ошибку? Добавьте ее в вопрос, вместе с деталями - хотя бы результатами ping для сайта

Comment: а проверить сайт (и айпи) по базам РКН? Вполне возможно, что сайт хостится на амазоне/DO/другом подобном и айпи общий...